# How to fully desaturate already desaturated colors in the composite

Tags: compositing-nodes, color

I am trying to raise the brightness of the blues as seen from the hue correct node but when I do, it picks up the slight blues in the grey and making them brighter. how do I filter out the desaturated colors from just the hue correct node if that makes sense?

[image: my composite setup]